# stdlib "Unique" method does not work

Tags: c++, unique, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to use the C++ Standard Library algorithm `unique` (with `BinaryPredicate`).

I've created a vector of pairs; each pair is like "(first=a vector of 4 doubles, second=an integer)". The second element serves as index so after using `unique, I can still tell the original index.

In the example below, I've created something like this:

---

```
10 20 30 40, 1
10 20 30 40, 2
10 20 30 40, 3
10 20 30 40, 4
10 20 30 40, 5
10 20 30 40, 6
```

---

Now I want to use the unique function to compare only the first element of each pair. I've used a customize binary predictor `uniquepred`. Indeed, it works, but the vector is not reduced after using `unique`.

#### EXPECTED RESULT

```
Size before=6
equal!
equal!
equal!
equal!
equal!
Size after=1
```

#### ACTUAL RESULT

```
Size before=6
equal!
equal!
equal!
equal!
equal!
Size after=6
```

Minimum working example follows. Please help me debugging this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<double> V1db;
typedef std::pair<V1db, int > Pairs;
typedef std::vector<Pairs> Vpairs;

bool uniquepred( const Pairs& l, const Pairs& r) {
    if (l.first==r.first)
        cout<<"equal!"<<endl;
    return l.first == r.first;
}
int main()
{
    Vpairs ak;
    V1db u2(4);
    u2[0]=10;u2[1]=20;u2[2]=30;u2[3]=40;
    Pairs m2;
    m2.first = u2;
    m2.second= 1;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    m2.second= 2;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    m2.second= 3;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    m2.second= 4;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    m2.second= 5;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    m2.second= 6;
    ak.push_back(m2);
    cout<<"Size before="<<ak.size()<<endl;
    unique(ak.begin(), ak.end(), uniquepred);
    cout<<"Size after="<<ak.size()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for complete, minimal example. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Think about this for a moment: You pass nothing but iterators to `std::unique()`; specifically, you do not pass the container. How is function supposed to erase elements from the container without being passed the container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to do:

```
ak.erase(unique(ak.begin(), ak.end(), uniquepred), ak.end());
```

The reason for this is that `std::unique` reorders the values. It doesn't delete them though and you are left with a new range, from `begin()` to the iterator that `unique` returns. The container itself is not altered, other than this reordering.

There's no "remove at position X" method on vectors, even if there was it would invalidate the iterators. The `unique` algorithm by design doesn't even know anything about the underlying container, so it can work with any valid pair of iterators. The only requirement is that they are `ForwardIterators`.

Comment: If you're interested the documentation I used was: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique.html - Note [1] is particularly relevant here.

Answer (score 6):

`std::unique` *does* work; you forgot to look it up in your favourite C++ library documentation to find out what it does.

It functions a little weirdly, like `std::remove`, in that it actually just moves stuff around and gives you the end iterator to the new range. The underlying container is not resized: you have to do erasure yourself:

```
ak.erase(std::unique(ak.begin(), ak.end(), uniquepred), ak.end());
```

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks! Though I must protest: it is nobody's job to "counteract" somebody else's right to vote.

Comment: the vote seemed to be erroneous in my view too and unless I missed a mistake (which the downvoter neglected to point out) it's definitely not right for this answer to be scored 0 or negatively.

Comment: @awoodland: Individually, we don't vote for the final score; we vote for +1 or 0 or -1. :) What the final score ends up being is _separate_ from how we decide to cast our vote. Thanks for the support, though!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - that's often not how I vote - I normally vote +1, 0 or -1 on if I think the answer is currently under/over rated.

Comment: @awoodland: That's a subversion of the system, and an affront to democracy! You're supposed to be voting on the post, but instead you're voting on the votes.